# Replacing spaces with dashes in the url with angularjs and urlserviceprovider

Tags: angularjs

I have asked this question before and although someone produced a plunker showing it working. I have been unable to get it to work at all.
The plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mO4ZFUwCW7uX45tgmtcK?p=preview

I am trying to create a **state** that will replace spaces with dashes, so I created this:

```
$urlServiceProvider.config.type('productName', {
    encode: function (str) { return str && str.replace(/ /g, '-'); },
    decode: function (str) { return str && str.replace(/-/g, ' '); },
    is: angular.isString,
    pattern: /[^/]+/
});
```

Which should replace spaces with dashes.
The plunker above works, but it would not work in my project. So I created a new project and then added the code. I have made this project public so you can download it and test it locally.
It is located here: https://github.com/r3plica/angular-tests

Can someone look at it for me and tell me why it doesn't work? It is a very simple project (almost as simple as the plunker above.
Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project adds the custom parameter type *after* the states have been registered.  The parameter type has to exist *before* the state is registered.

Define a new angularjs module (let's call it `testsApp.routerConfig`) which defines the custom parameter type.

```
function configureApp($locationProvider, $urlServiceProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true });

    $urlServiceProvider.config.type('productName', {
        encode: function (str) { return str && str.replace(/ /g, '-'); },
        decode: function (str) { return str && str.replace(/-/g, ' '); },
        is: angular.isString,
        pattern: /[^/]+/
    });
}

angular.module('testsApp.routerConfig', ['ui.router']).config(configureApp);
```

Make sure that the routerConfig module is processed before modules that register states (which use the parameter type).

```
var testsApp = angular.module('testsApp', ['testsApp.routerConfig', 'testsApp.core']);
```

This example assumes your states are registered by a module named `testsApp.core`